# Adjustable Panels In a Display using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have an application that uses Swing.   The display I am working on, uses a Box with a Horizontal Layout as the top container.   In it, are three other boxes (which actually contain the content).   The appearance to the user is a window with three panes, arranged horizontally across the screen.    What I want to do is give the user the ability to change the pane sizes (the width of the panes).    I tried putting the interior boxes in a JTable, that failed miserably.   Any other ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a nested [JSplitPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).